# Looking for entity framework cf migration after db model change with no loose of data manual

Tags: database, entity-framework, migration, ef-code-first

I'm using Code First notation of Entity Framework, and got some problem after changing model.
 I don't use initializer's so my db isn't recreated. And that's good, cuz there is already to much info.
 I'd be very grateful for some advices and better manuals of the best practice how to change db with no loose of current data.
 Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If can you do it you should upgrade to [Entity Framework 4.3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-released.aspx).

It introduces among other new features: the [New Code First Migrations Feature](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-code-based-migrations-walkthrough.aspx).

Otherwise you can manually create and run change scripts or you can use a thrid party migration framework like [fluentmigrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator) or you can write your own.

Answer (score 0):

BACKUP your data/db/project/solution now, and 5 mins from now, and 5 mins after that, etc.

Are you using Visual Studio? You can use server explorer to manipulate the database. You would have to connect to the db (in SQL server or the actual db file), connect, and then you will be able to change table names, columns, etc. in the db.

Comment: Sorry, but I meaned some upgrades among data structure, which make project invalid, until db is recreated.